# Al vs. El - Uses and differences

Tags: traducción, gramática

So I have been trying to translate the sentence "the Government lacks money". My understanding is that the correct answer is to say *"al Gobierno le falta dinero"*.

Why is it *al Gobierno* and not *el Gobierno*? Is the Government being treated as a person, and if so then why is it not simply *a Gobierno*?  Is there ever a way (that is, does it give it a different meaning) I could say *el Gobierno*? Is this specific to *faltar*?

Related — I understood from a Venezuelan friend that I could say *"el Gobierno necesita dinero"*.  Similarly I could say *"al perro le falta comida"* but for a person it is *"a Sara le falta comida"*.

Any clarity on how and why this rule works would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Checking the *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas*, I see that the verb *[faltar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=faltar)* is an intransitive verb. So, in the sentence

> Al gobierno le falta dinero.

"Dinero" is the subject, and "al gobierno" is the indirect object. That's why in all these sentences the object always has the preposition *a*:

> A la paella le falta sal.
>   Al juguete le faltan pilas.
>   A este piso le faltan habitaciones.
>   A la mesa le falta estabilidad.

Note also that the verb agrees with the subject. It's tricky because this is a case in which the order of the sentence is inverted: the indirect object goes first, and the subject goes last. It's a similar case as the construction

> A María le gusta Pedro.

Comment: I think @williamb will better understand if you add that "**Al** Gobierno" is the short and correct way to say "**A el** Gobierno"

Answer (score 3):

Intransitive verbs such as *gustar* and *faltar* need to have an indirect object. When this is a common noun, we say *al* / *a la*, but with a proper noun when can only use *a*.

Examples:

> A Sara le gusta el chocolate
>
> Al perro le gusta el chocolate
>
> A la mujer le gusta el chocolate

And the same with *faltar*/*molestar*/*interesar*/*encantar*, etc.

> A Sara le molesta el ruido
>
> Al perro le molesta el ruido
>
> A la mujer le molesta el ruido

Extra note:

Please also remember that *señor*/*señora*/*señorita* and *doctor* always take the article when you refer to them (but when not speaking to them directly) so:

> Al señor López le interesa esta película.

But no *a* when speaking directly to him:

> Señor López, ¿le interesa esta película?